# Conectar Laravel con base de datos ORACLE

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, oracle-11g, laravel-8

he hecho una instalacion nueva de laravel, version 8.34.0
tengo oracle 11g instalado.
Luego le he agregado el plugin para conectarme a oracle.

```
composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:^8
```

y agregué el dll, en la extension de php.

luego instalé mi plantilla,

```
composer require jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte
```

y posteriormente, pase a instalar el login mediante:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

e instalé, las vistas de login

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

y sobreescribí estas vistas de login, con las que trae la plantilla

```
php artisan adminlte:install --only=auth_views
```

me pasaron una bd oracle, con las tablas y campos ya listos, y me pidieron conectarme a ella.
asi que validé la tabla de usuarios, y esta tiene otro nombre, y los campos tienen otros nombres no estandard de laravel.

```
tabla= USUARIOSTBL
id= CODIGOUSUARIO
email = EMAILTEMP
password = LACLAVE
```

asi que, no vi problema en cambiar el modelo USER, e indicarle esos campos, de la siguiente manera:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    // , Notifiable

    protected $table = "USUARIOSTBL";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'CODIGOUSUARIO';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'NOMUSUARIO',
        'EMAILTEMP',
        'LACLAVE',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'LACLAVE',
        // 'remember_token',
    ];
```

tambien indiqué otros cambios en loginController y agregué esta linea:

```
**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'EMAILTEMP'; 
    }
```

mi archivo .env tiene bien las conexiones a la bd:

```
DB_CONNECTION=oracle
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1521
DB_DATABASE=XE
DB_USERNAME=BD_ORACLE
DB_PASSWORD=oracle214577
```

estos datos ya los validé, ya que cuando ingreso por OracleSql Developer, e ingreso estos datos.
me conecto y puedo ver las tablas y los campos, etc.

cuando ingreso al login, e ingreso un correo, y una contraseña almacenada en mi bd.
simplemente no hace nada, recarga y no me muestra ningun mensaje de error, le coloco un correo y un pass invalido, y tampoco me muestra ningun error. simplemente no hace nada.
antes de modificar el login controller, indicandole que el username es EMAILTEMP.
me marca este error:

```
Error Code : 904 Error Message : ORA-00904: "EMAIL": invalid identifier Position : 49 Statement : select * from (select * from "USUARIOSTBL" where "EMAIL" = :p0) where rownum = 1 Bindings : [admin@admin.com] (SQL: select * from (select * from "USUARIOSTBL" where "EMAIL" = admin@admin.com) where rownum = 1)
```

en cuanto edito el logincontroller, y le agrego el

```
 public function username()
        {
            return 'EMAILTEMP'; 
        }
```

ya el error desaparece, pero simplemente ya no hace nada.
cuando fui al log de laravel, me encuentro con caracteres extraños, tipos "CHINOS" y no puedo ver nada.

me sale un mensaje al ver el log.  "fix the file"
el unico error que me sale, por consola es:

```
GET http://localhost/oracle/public/vendor/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

pero considero que es algo que no importa, solo me indica que no encuentra un css.

sin embargo ejecuté el comando,

```
npm install icheck-bootstrap
```

para ver si solucionaba algo y no, sigue exactamente igual.
reinicie servicios, reinicie pc, reinicie XAMPP, todo, y sigue igual.

que puedo hacer? que me falta por cambiar?
gracias a quien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Las contraseñas están con hash o como texto plano?

Comment: la contraseña en la bd, la tengo como hash, fui a bcrypt online y me generé una contrasena, la copié y la pegué en la bd, para no tener problema